# listview with base adapter inside a fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

i have a list view with a bade adapter it's actually a static one each row contains 2 text views and an image the problem is i tried to put it in a fragment in activity it works perfectly fine but a did put it in a fragment class it gives me errors the row contains an intent to another activity but the intent gives an error and also setting the adpater to the list view gives another error
 here is the code:

```
public class consulterfragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
ListView list;
@Nullable    
@Override    
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.consulter_fragment_layout,container,false) ;
    list= (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    list.setAdapter(new SanaAdapter(this));
    list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    return view;

}
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, note_details.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    MyViewHolder holder = (MyViewHolder) view.getTag();
    SingleRow temp = (SingleRow) holder.myImage.getTag();
    intent.putExtra("titles", temp.titles);
    startActivity(intent);
}

class SingleRow {
    String titles;
    String description;
    int image;

    SingleRow(String titles, String description, int image) {
        this.titles = titles;
        this.description = description;
        this.image = image;
    }
}
class MyViewHolder {
    ImageView myImage;
    TextView myTitle;
    TextView myDescription;

    MyViewHolder(View v) {
        myImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        myTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        myDescription = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    }
}

class SanaAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<SingleRow> list;
    Context context;

    SanaAdapter(Context c) {
        context = c;
        list = new ArrayList<SingleRow>();
        Resources res = c.getResources();
        String[] titles = res.getStringArray(R.array.titles);
        String[] descriptions = res.getStringArray(R.array.decriptions);
        int[] images = {R.drawable.ico1, R.drawable.ico2, R.drawable.ico3, R.drawable.ico4, R.drawable.ico5, R.drawable.ico6, R.drawable.ico7, R.drawable.ico8,
                R.drawable.ico9, R.drawable.ico10, R.drawable.ico1, R.drawable.ico2, R.drawable.ico3, R.drawable.ico4, R.drawable.ico5, R.drawable.ico6, R.drawable.ico7, R.drawable.ico8,
                R.drawable.ico9, R.drawable.ico10};
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            list.add(new SingleRow(titles[i], descriptions[i], images[i]));
        }
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return list.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertview, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View row = convertview;
        MyViewHolder holder = null;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notelist_row, viewGroup, false);
            holder = new MyViewHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);
            Log.d("SANA", "Creating a new row");
        } else {
            holder = (MyViewHolder) row.getTag();
            Log.d("SANA", "Recycling shit hhhhhh");
        }

        SingleRow temp = list.get(i);

        holder.myTitle.setText(temp.titles);
        holder.myDescription.setText(temp.description);
        holder.myImage.setImageResource(temp.image);
        return row;
        }
    }
}
```

the first error is in setting the adapter
it says `SanaAdapter(android.context.Context)` in `SanaAdapter` cannot be applied

the second error is in the intent it says 
cannot resolve constructor `Intent(com.example.hp.memorybackup.consulterfragment,java.lang.class<com.example.hp.memorybackup.notedetails>)`

i really apreciate your help

Comment: Use `getActivity()` instead of `this`

Answer (score 3):

In onCreateView you are calling

```
list.setAdapter(new SanaAdapter(this));
```

But correct will be

```
list.setAdapter(new SanaAdapter(getActivity());
```

Also it should be hightlighted, is it? Fragment extends Object, it is not child of Context.